# How to feed static bitmap frames from GIF to wxpython shaped frame

Tags: python, animation, wxpython, gif

I am struggling to figure out how to submit bitmap frames from a user selected GIF (which has a transparent background) and display the GIF/frames without creating additional UI elements that remove the transparency. (Assume the user's desktop environment does not support transparent windows).

The closest solution is provided here: [How to blit a image directly to the screen without a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876903)

However this solution only supports a single image. I am attempting to modify the code found [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3292) to translate the GIF into frames and then force wxPython to display each frame but I am completely lost on how to time the display of frames or if this is even the right approach. I have copied the code I am working with below.

```py
import wx
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

IMAGE_PATH = 'TEST.gif'
im = Image.open(IMAGE_PATH)

index = 1
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
    frame.save("frame%d.png" % index)
    index += 1

class ShapedFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Shaped Window",
                style = wx.FRAME_SHAPED | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.hasShape = False
        self.delta = wx.Point(0,0)            
        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
        self.SetClientSize((self.bmp.GetWidth(), self.bmp.GetHeight()))
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)
        self.SetWindowShape()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnDoubleClick)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnLeftUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_WINDOW_CREATE, self.SetWindowShape)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
    def OnEraseBackground(self,evt=None):
        pass        
    def SetWindowShape(self, evt=None):
        r = wx.RegionFromBitmap(self.bmp)
        self.hasShape = self.SetShape(r)
    def OnDoubleClick(self, evt):
        if self.hasShape:
            self.SetShape(wx.Region())
            self.hasShape = False
        else:
            self.SetWindowShape()
    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)
    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close()
    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
        origin = self.GetPosition()
        self.delta = wx.Point(pos.x - origin.x, pos.y - origin.y)
    def OnMouseMove(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
            newPos = (pos.x - self.delta.x, pos.y - self.delta.y)
            self.Move(newPos)
    def OnLeftUp(self, evt):
        if self.HasCapture():
            self.ReleaseMouse()

i = 0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        while i >= index:
        # Load the image
        img = 'frame%s.png' % (i)
        image = wx.Image(img, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)        
        app = wx.PySimpleApp()
        ShapedFrame().Show()
        app.MainLoop()
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I not sure what you're trying to achieve with the "shapedframe' business but this should point you in the right direction.
I'm filling the screen with the frames from a `gif` file, changing the frame every 1/2 a second (500 milliseconds), looping back to the begining upon reaching the final frame.
It's a classic case for the use of a `wx.Timer`.
Obviously you can lose the `Scale` routine if it's not required.

```
import wx
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
IMAGE_PATH = 'TEST.gif'
im = Image.open(IMAGE_PATH)
imgs=[]

index = 1
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
    frame.save("frame%d.png" % index)
    imgs.append("frame%d.png" % index)
    index += 1

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Gif Frames")
        self.screenW = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric( wx.SYS_SCREEN_X )
        self.screenH = wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric( wx.SYS_SCREEN_Y )
        self.SetSize(self.screenW,self.screenH)
        self.image_counter = 0
        image = wx.Image(imgs[self.image_counter], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.size = image.GetSize()
        bitmap = self.Scale(image)
        self.img = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, bitmap)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.Show()
        self.timer.Start(500)

    def Scale(self,image):
        image = image.Scale(self.screenW,self.screenH, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        #image = image.Scale(self.size[0],self.size[1], wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        result = wx.Bitmap(image)
        return result


    def OnTimer(self, event):
        #New frame every 1/2 a second
        self.image_counter +=1
        if self.image_counter > len(imgs) -1:
            self.image_counter = 0
        image = wx.Image(imgs[self.image_counter], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        bitmap = self.Scale(image)
        self.img.SetBitmap(bitmap)

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        MyFrame()
        app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: The shaped frame is being used to preserve transparency in organic shaped animations (ex: pacman going in a circle with no background) and so far that works for a single frame. Also I am struggling to get your code to work, I keep getting "TypeError: String or Unicode type required" for lines 22 and 32

Comment: I suspect that you are using python2.7 and wxpython2.8, my code is written for python3. Use `result = image.ConvertToBitmap()` instead of `result = wx.Bitmap(image)`